# Does the Produce Flame spell trigger the Flames of Plegethos feat's ability to cause flames to wreathe you?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, damage

I have a player in my campaign who took the [Flames of Phlegethos](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/flames-of-phlegethos) tiefling racial feat (from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 74-75). One of its benefits is:

> Whenever you cast a spell that deals fire damage, you can cause flames
> to wreathe you until the end of your next turn. The flames don’t harm
> you or your possessions, and they shed bright light out to 30 feet and
> dim light for an additional 30 feet. While the flames are present, any
> creature within 5 feet of you that hits you with a melee attack takes
> 1d4 fire damage.

Additionally, he took the *[produce flame](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/produce-flame)* cantrip:

> A flickering flame appears in your hand. The flame remains there for
> the duration [...]
>
> You can also attack with the flame. When you cast this spell, or as an
> action on a later turn, you can hurl the flame at a creature within 30
> feet of you. Make a ranged spell attack. On a hit, the target takes 1d8
> fire damage.

If he casts the *produce flame* cantrip and holds it (i.e. doesn't attack or attempt to deal damage with it), would that still trigger this benefit of the Flames of Phlegethos feat?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Yes

He's cast a spell.  Check.
That spell deals fire damage.  Check.
He's good.

Now, he doesn't get the effect if/when he throws it on a later round, but it totally counts for the round he cast it.

If it had said "when you cast a spell and it deals fire damage" that would be a different story, as that would require that fire damage had actually been dealt.  (It also wouldn't work if you threw a fire bolt and missed, or in some other way failed to successfully deal your damage.)  In this case, though, it's checking for "deals fire damage" as a feature of the spell that you cast.