# Does a missed Green-Flame Blade trigger Flames of Phlegethos wreath?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats

Similar to [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124071/does-produce-flame-trigger-flames-of-plegethos) question but replace *produce flame* with a missed melee attack with *green-flame blade*.

If I cast *green-flame blade* but miss the melee attack with the weapon, does the benefit of Flames of Phlegethos still trigger?

I would think the answer is also yes but I just wanted to make sure I'm not making a logical jump.

Comment: Can you edit this question to at least summarise what you're asking? Because right now your question is effectively "Does this happen when I miss?" which doesn't make much sense. Also it's a good practice, to avoid link rot.

Comment: Thanks for help editing. So to clarify, people marking this question as a duplicate of the one I linked are saying that the answer is also yes? That yes the wreath from Flames of Phlegethos still trigger even if the melee attack misses?

Comment: @Kreakdude yes.  It works, for the same reason the other one works.  Green-flame blade is a spell.  That spell deals fire damage.  You cast it.  That's all you need.